# A mapping from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ that does not increase distances

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is there a mapping from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ such that for any $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$ and their images $x', y' \in \mathbb R^m$, $\|x'-y'\|_2 \leq k \|x-y\|_2$ for some $k \geq 1$? Ideally, $k$ would be very close to $1$? Also, ideally, $m$ would be $1$.

I think the subject is related to bounded linear maps but I am not familiar with the field. My background is computer science and robotics, and such a projection would be very, very useful for motion planning.

Comment: What do you mean by projection? (it is usually a linear mapping such that $P^2=P$). As an aside, all linear maps on finite dimensional spaces are bounded. Orthogonal projections have $\|P\| \le 1$, which is what you want.

Comment: You need to provide more info. Just talking the first component  will produce a map that satisfies your requirement, but it is not a projection in the usual sense of the word.

Comment: It might also be helpful if you added a quick description of how you plan to use this "projection"

Comment: You probably won't like this, but $F\equiv 0$, which sends everything to the zero vector, meets the stated requirements.

Answer (score 0):

From your use of the term "projection", it seems as if you are assuming $m \le n$ and that you are identifying $\mathbb{R}^m$ with a coordinate subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, namely the set of all $n$-tuples of the form $(x_1,…,x_m,0,…,0)$. And in that case the map
$$x = (x_1,…,x_m,x_{m+1},…,x_n) \mapsto (x_1,…,x_m,0,…,0) = x'
$$
has the property you want, that $||x'-y'||_2 \le ||x - y||_2$, with constant $k=1$.

Or, if you do wish instead to think of $\mathbb{R}^m$ as just $m$-tuples without all those extra zeros, you can write instead
$$x = (x_1,…,x_m,x_{m+1},…,x_n) \mapsto (x_1,…,x_m) = x'
$$
although, as comments say, this is not usually thought of as a "projection".